# SQL BETWEEN strings where second one is the smallest

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get all the records that have a reference strings that applies to compStringA <= refstring <= compStringB

A and B are given in by the users of the application. When I try to use `tableA.referenceString
  BETWEEN compStringB
  AND compStringA`
 it returns no values.
I don't have control over what string is put in first.

Is there a way to make this return the rows that I need?

I use MySQL Server 5.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
where tableA.referenceString >= least(compStringA, compStringB) and
      tableA.referenceString <= greatest(compStringA, compStringB)
```

Comment: I guess second condition would be `<=` ?

Comment: Can I use the least and greatest functions within my between? Or does this create performance issues or something like that?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yeah think so too, minor typo's can happen

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid . . . Do you have documentation for that?  I would expect the performance to be the same.